# error jquery uncaught typeError Object [object Object] has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery

my jquery has a problem my code is:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      ad = jQuery.noConflict();
       ad(document).ready(function(){
         ad('.popbox').popbox({
           'open'          : '.open',
           'box'           : '.box',
           'arrow'         : '.arrow',
           'arrow-border'  : '.arrow-border',
           'close'         : '.close'
          });
       });
```

i'm using this code in a site and it's work but now use another site and it's not work
i see in google chrome console an my error this:
error jquery uncaught typeError Object [object Object] has no method 'popbox'

Comment: Which method doesn't it have? Most likely reason is you're not loading the `popbox` jQuery plugin, or you're loading it before jQuery.

Comment: Or it's being loaded after the wrong jquery if there's more than one.

Comment: i'm loading popbox.js befor my code in my page

Comment: Are you loading jQuery more than once?

Comment: Which line is giving this error?  What .js files are you loading and in what order?

Comment: my error at this line ad('.popbox').popbox({ error no method popbox